# How can I still stay on the old tab when a new webpage is opened in new tab in Internet Explorer 9.0?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

In Internet Explorer 9.0, when I click a link of a webpage to open a new webpage in a new tab, Internet Explorer 9 switches to the new tab automatically.

I hope I can still stay on the old tab when a new tab is opened, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Tabs -> Settings, untick this box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

I have unchecked the option, but I get the same result

You can access www.asp.net, and click a link in "Daily Community Spotlight", you will still switch to new tab

Comment: Your other option may be to hold Ctrl while clicking the link.